# How to select element inside CKEditor by class using Jquery

Tags: ckeditor

I cannot find out how to select element inside CKEditor by class using jQuery selector, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did the answer by oleq work for you? If so, maybe accept? Did you manage to get a selection done based on the jquery? I'm trying that and I keep not succeeding.

Answer (score 12):

`CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.window.getFrame().$` retrieves a native DOM element for editor editable area. So:

```
$( CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.window.getFrame().$ ).contents().find( anything );
```

Should solve your problem.

---

Also note that CKEditor provides an API for DOM manipulation:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.getById( 'someId' );
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.getElementsByTag( 'div' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
$(youreditor.document.find('anything'))
```

where youreditor is

```
youreditor = CKEDITOR.replace( '' ... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using **jQuery Adapter** (tested on 4.4.3 version)

```
$( $('.your_selector').ckeditor().editor.window.getFrame().$).contents().find('a.super_link')
```